# How to include sender's details in email body?

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I have a macro in MS Word which:

- Creates an Outlook email on the click of a button
- Attaches the Word document to the Outlook email

I want to include the sender's details (name, email address, etc.) in the body of the email.

```
    Dim Outlook_Object As Object
    
    Dim Email_Object As Object
    Dim This_document As Document
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    
    Set Outlook_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email_Object = Outlook_Object.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set This_document = ActiveDocument
    
    This_document.Save
    With Email_Object
        .Subject = "REPORT REQUEST FORM"
        .Body = "This is a test email."
        .To = "john.smith@gmail.com"
        .Importance = olImportanceNormal
        .Attachments.Add This_document.FullName
        .Display
   
    End With
    Set This_document = Nothing
    Set Email_Object = Nothing
    Set Outlook_Object = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Do you mean like a signature? because there are plenty of SO tutorials for how to do that.

Comment: Nope, not the signature.

Comment: Well, you must mean the information Eugene gave you then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NameSpace.CurrentUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.currentuser) property which returns the display name of the currently logged-on user as a `Recipient` object. The [Recipient.AddressEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.addressentry) property returns the `AddressEntry` object corresponding to the resolved recipient. Then you can get the `Name` and `Address` properties like shown below:

```
Dim ns as Outlook.NameSpace

Set ns = OutlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI")

' to get the email address of the sender
ns.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address

' to get the name
ns.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Name
```

To include this information to the message body you can use the `Body` or `HTMLBody` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using [WScript.Network](https://ss64.com/vb/network.html)

```
Function GetUserFullName() As String
    Dim WSHnet, UserName, UserDomain, objUser
    Set WSHnet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    UserName = WSHnet.UserName
    UserDomain = WSHnet.UserDomain
    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & UserDomain & "/" & UserName & ",user")
    GetUserFullName = objUser.FullName
End Function
```

Also, instead of using **.body**, I used **.HTMLbody** for the email message body [where I invoked GetUserFullName()]

```
.HTMLbody = "Request submitted by:" & "<br>" & GetUserFullName()
```